# create an array whose length is determined by user input: C vs C99 vs Java

Tags: java, c, c99

I am trying to figure out methods to create an array whose length is determined at run time (e.g., by user input) in C and Java.

In C, I know that some versions of C standards such as C99 now allow the following way:

```
int size;
scanf("%d",&size);
int arr[size];
```

However, theoretically, it is not acceptable to create a dynamic array in C like this. The global solution is to use malloc() in C.

My question is, what about in Java? I have run the following Java program on my own computer and no error was generated. But I am not sure whether it is only correct to a specific Java platform (like C99 in the C case) or it is universally acceptable in all Java's

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    int size;

    System.out.println("enter a number:");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    size = s.nextInt();

    int[] arr = new int[size];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with allocating an array's size this way

Comment: @YassinHajaj No. c99 is a version of C standard. Other C standards include c11, etc

Comment: The behavior and workings of arrays in Java are fully specified, see [Java Language Specification version 10, chapter 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-10.html). Frankly, I'm amazed you even think that Java - a fully managed language - would somehow skip that for arrays.

Comment: `int arr[size];` is not a dynamic array. It is an automatic array whose size is determined at run-time. The lifetime of an automatic object only extends to the moment execution leaves the block in which it was declared. Dynamic objects live until *explicitly* freed.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly acceptable and commonly done in Java. `new int[number]` is executed at runtime and a dynamic number does it.

As long as the length of the array is a non-negative `int`, this is valid in Java.

Comment: Even if it is a negative int, it is valid Java. It will fail at runtime; but so might a positive integer if it is too big for the available memory. (Also, you mean non-negative, not positive: zero is a fine length for an array). (Also, the length needn't be an int; it merely needs to be a type which undergoes unary numeric promotion to int).

Comment: Then is the array allocated on heap or stack? I know in C/C++, static arrays are allocated on stack while dynamic arrays are allocated on heap. But in Jave, it looks like the ways to create a static array (e.g., int[] static_arr = new int[5]) and a dynamic array (e.g., int[] dynamic_arr = new int[n]; // n determined by user input) are the same.  Then are they allocated both on heap rather than one on stack and one on heap? @Ernest Kiwele

Comment: @Jane Java arrays are Objects, so they are always heap allocated.

Comment: @AndyTurner Good point about non-negative length, I've edited. Regarding a negative int passing compile-time validation, that's obvious, but I suppose the question is more about the dynamic aspect of the array creation. There are many possible reasons for errors to occur at runtime, but that doesn't make the dynamic creation essentially problematic.

Answer (score 0):

In java you are able to set the length of the array as the creation of the array is executed during runtime and should be accepted in all java platforms.

Answer (score 0):

In Java an array is allocated on heap. If the allocation fails, a catchable exception is thrown! It is possible to recover from failed array allocation.

```
% java Main
enter a number:
1231231231
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Catch the exception:

```
try {
    int[] arr = new int[size];
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    System.out.println("Alas, such array could not be allocated. Try a smaller number next time!");
}
```

and you get

```
% java Main      
enter a number:
1231231231
Alas, such array could not be allocated. Try a smaller number next time!
```

---

The reason why the simple use of variable-length arrays in C99 is often frowned upon is that the array is allocated on **stack**. Now, if the size of the array comes from the user, it is easy to cause an uncontrollable crash:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    volatile int arr[size];
    printf("%d\n", arr[size - 1]);
}
```

now compile and run:

```
% ./a.out    
1231231231  
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

There is *no way* of checking whether the allocation succeeded or not. Therefore if you're unsure - and especially when playing with numbers that could come from an untrusted user, you shouldn't use stack-allocated variable-length arrays.

Comment: Of course, seg faults from optimistic memory allocation are *completely different*. :-)

Comment: @rici: I would like to see the C Standard require that implementations document "environmental requirements", and then say that if environmental conditions are satisfied and a program does not invoke UB, an implementation must either behave as defined by the Standard or fail in implementation-defined manner.  If a C compiler specifies an environmental requirement that the OS must let the program run, but an OS kills off a process for reasons outside that program's control, such action would violate the documented environmental requirements, thus waiving any requirements on the implementation.